# what will be the efficient way to expose large JSON parsed object in java to the UI?

Tags: java, angularjs, json, file, streaming

I have a java listener which live streams the feeds from social web. I need to display these stream instantly on UI (AngularJS) as it created. What will be the best practice tp achieve it?

- Writing a JSON file and calling it from UI?
- Dumping the stream to Queue and from queue to UI?

or any other way to implement it fast and efficient would be helpful.

Comment: If your backend was nodejs and not java it would have been much easier. You could have used socket.io to move data instantly from server to browser, any chance you can use nodejs instead of java?

Comment: I can give a shot. But will I be able to expose it as rest API kind to UI? And which would be the best socket.io or binaryJS?

Comment: it won't be exposed as a Rest API to the UI. Your server side code running on Node.JS will be able to retrieve the data from the social sources, and immediately push the updates to the connected client in real time, so your angular code on the browser won't need to poll the server frequently to get updates. Once the client gets the updates in can display it to the user in real time. I do not have experience with binaryJS but I can say that socket.io is much more popular and has large community support

Comment: Thanks Hisham! much needed idea. Will give it a try,

Comment: You are welcome, I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use NodeJS for the backend instead of Java. If you do so You use [socket.io](http://socket.io) to move data instantly from server to browser

Your server side code running on Node.JS will be able to retrieve the data from the social sources, and immediately push the updates to the connected client in real time, so your angular code on the browser won't need to poll the server frequently to get updates. Once the client gets the updates it can display it to the user in real time.